# Can we incorporate the Speech Recognition framework with Today Extension

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, today-extension, avaudioengine

I am trying to build a widget which has a speech button. When I press it , it should convert the speech uttered to text. 
However when I try to record the voice , AVAudioEngine fails to start. Is it because AVAudioEngine is not allowed in Today Extension?

Answer (score 2):

Searching the internet I seem to have found my answer. The short answer is no, you can't [record Audio in extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1872/_index.html).