# How to trigger keyboard to open with dictation enabled when selecting button

Tags: ios, swift

How can I have dictation show when pressing on a button in a UIViewController.

I see that this is done when the microphone is selected in the search field in Apple Store App. But I am not sure how this same action can be replicated in Swift.

**The following image shows what I would like to accomplish:**

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I just need to know how to write a function that brings up dictation right away

Comment: Have you had made the audio equaliser view or the dictation you are asking to show.

Comment: Hi @PeterDavon this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849787/recognize-speech-to-text-swift

Comment: @ShivamGaur Dictation view is already made, its in the keyboard..I just want to present it when a button is pressed.

Comment: @PeterDavon you can not use keyboard dictation view , there is no api or property to use it, you have to make your custom one, please go trough this link - https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/speech-recognition-with-swift-in-ios-10-50d5f4e59c48

Comment: Hello john were you able so solve this?